# Как вызывать отдельную строку из CSV файла?

Tags: python, массивы, csv

У меня есть CSV-файл, в котором лежат ссылки (скрин)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть Python код, который считывает таблицу и выводит ссылки на экран

```
    with open("data.csv", newline='') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")
        for line in reader:
            print(line)
```

**Вопрос: Как доставать ссылки выборочно? Допустим сначала 6-ю, потом 2-ю и т.д.?**

Возможно надо как-то создать уникальную переменную (массив), и присвоить ей свою ссылку, чтобы я мог обращаться к этой переменной, используя массив, для вывода нужной мне ссылки

*Надеюсь смог понятно объяснить*

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: попробуйте модель pandas, читайте csv-файл с помощью него и обращайтесь к любой строке с помощью встроенных локаторов. И если вы хотите, чтобы вам ответили конкретнее, добавьте в вопрос исходные данные в воспроизводимом виде. а не скриншотом.

Comment: url  = reader[5] url1 = reader[1] и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Функция get_link() принимает первоначальный индекс start_row с которого будет
начинаться считывание ссылок.

```
import openpyxl

def get_link(start_row):

   path = r"E:\baza.xlsx" # путь к excel файлу
   my_file = openpyxl.open(path)
   sheet = my_file.active

   for row in range(start_row, sheet.max_row + 1):
        link = sheet[row][0].value # [0] колонка А в excel
        print('link: ',link)
   my_file.save(path)

get_link(3)
```

Comment: У меня расширение файла не .xlsx, а .csv

Comment: Да виноват, не досмотрел. Для меня все excel. Даже интересно в чем разница. Думаю конвертнуть не проблема csv to xlsx.